# Foreach loop only returns the latest result from a query in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, loops, foreach

I want to loop through a collection and do a query for each item of this collection but the foreach loop only returns the latest result. How can I solve this problem?

```
foreach ($conversations as $conversation) {

    if ($conversation->id_participant1 !== Auth::user()->id) {

        $users = User::where(function ($query) use ($conversation) {
            $query->where('id', $conversation->id_participant1);
        })
            ->get();
    } else {
        $users = User::where(function ($query) use ($conversation) {
            $query->where('id', $conversation->id_participant2);
        })
            ->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include input, expected output and actual output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are overwriting in every loop $user variable
you can create empty array on the top of foreach, and push users to that variable

```
$users = []
foreach ($conversations as $conversation) {

if ($conversation->id_participant1 !== Auth::user()->id) {

    $users[] = User::where(function ($query) use ($conversation) {
        $query->where('id', $conversation->id_participant1);
    })
        ->get();
} else {
    $users[] = User::where(function ($query) use ($conversation) {
        $query->where('id', $conversation->id_participant2);
    })
        ->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Armen it works, but I get this value

[{"id":2,"username":"space_cowboy","email":"space_cowboy@gmail.com","country":"South Africa","created_at":"2019-10-07 13:52:28","updated_at":"2019-10-07 13:52:28"}]

and I just want to use the username and the ID, how do I do that? I tried these: $users->id and $users['id'] they didn't work

Comment: you have an array, if you write $user[0]->id, you'll get the id of the first given user